# Widgets overriding their frame's background

Tags: python, background, tkinter, widget

When I create a frame and set a background color to it, the color shows up nicely. However, when I add a widget to the frame, the background color goes away. I have tried setting this same color to the background of the widgets, but there are still many white spots in the frame.

Here is the block of code that is not working:

```
    DAC_frame = Frame(self, width=180, height=240, bg="red")
    DAC_frame.pack(side=RIGHT)

    DAC_delete_label = Label(DAC_frame, text="Delete A Term:", bg="red")
    DAC_delete_label.pack(fill=X)

    DAC_delete_entry = Entry(DAC_frame)
    DAC_delete_entry.pack()

    DAC_delete = Button(DAC_frame, text="Delete Term")
    DAC_delete.pack()

    DAC_clear = Button(DAC_frame, text="Clear Dictionary")
    DAC_clear.pack()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not set a transparent color in Tkinter, that's why the background of your `Frame` is going away. So the "white spots" are just the background of your widgets. You have two options now:

1. Create your own widgets with `Canvas` [here is a example](http://www.python-forum.de/pastebin.php?mode=view&s=309)
2. Set same backgroundcolor to each widgets, for buttons you can set the `borderwidth` to 0.

   ```
   from Tkconstants import RIGHT, X
   from Tkinter import Frame, Tk, Label, Entry, Button
   import Tkinter


   class App(Tk):

       def __init__(self):
           Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
           DAC_frame = Frame(self, width=180, height=240, bg="red")
           DAC_frame.pack(side=RIGHT)

           DAC_delete_label = Label(DAC_frame, text="Delete A Term:", bg="red")
           DAC_delete_label.pack(fill=X)

           DAC_delete_entry = Entry(DAC_frame)
           DAC_delete_entry.pack()

           DAC_delete = Button(DAC_frame, text="Delete Term",borderwidth=0, bg="red", activebackground="red")
           DAC_delete.pack()

           DAC_clear = Button(DAC_frame, text="Clear Dictionary",borderwidth=0, bg="red", activebackground="red")
           DAC_clear.pack()

   ap = App()
   ap.mainloop()
   ```